# My bot can't take errors when failling to run a "join" voice channel command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently coding a `discord.js` bot and I made this `join` command so the bot can join my voice channel

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

let membervc = message.member.voice.channel;
let botvc = message.guild.me.voice.channel;
if(!membervc) return message.send('You need to join a voice channel first.');
if(botvc){
    if(!(botvc.members.size - 1)) return message.reply(`I am already on ${botvc}`);
    if(membervc.id == botvc.id) return message.reply('We are already on the same voice channel.');
};
membervc.join();
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to make it so that if the last function gets an error or doesn't work at all It can send an error message to the user like
`@User, I could not join the channel, "THE ERROR"` :/ I don't want my bot to crash and having to run it again just because of one small detail. Is there a way to fix it? It would help me a lot! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not let the user know about the error, because it might just confuse them, but you can do `try catch` to check if it goes through and if not message is sent.

```js
try {
      membervc.join();
} catch(error){
      console.log(error);
      message.reply(`Something went wrong while joining voice channel`);
}
```

Comment: Don't worry it's only me and some programmers who uses the bot so giving directly the error is a good thing ! Also thanks you so much it worked !!

Comment: Remember to add `await` before any promises (e.g. `membervc.join()` or `message.channel.send()`) to avoid any uncaught promise rejections (which will *not* be caught by the `catch`).